# Input Range que aumenta o tamanho do texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou a tentar criar um `<input type="range">` que aumenta e/ou diminui o tamanho do texto conforme o movemos para a esquerda ou para a direita.

Até agora tudo bem, consegui criar este efeito, mas agora queria colocar um número a indicar o `font-size` atual, após termos movido o `<input type="range">` e bloqueei nessa parte.

Eis o código que tenho até agora:

```js
$("#fader").on("input",function () {
    $('#v-28').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="valor-fontSize">40</p>
<input class="none" type="range" min="14" max="40" value="0" id="fader" step="1" >
    
<p id="v-28">
Após uma viagem que se prolongou por mais de nove anos e em que percorreu 4,8 mil milhões de quilómetros a New Horizons passou o mais perto de Plutão às 11:49 TMG (12:49 em Lisboa) em piloto automático, divulgou a NASA na rede social Twitter.
</p>
```

Aqui está um exemplo no jsFiddle também: http://jsfiddle.net/Lucp945b/

> Se fosse um `input` que desse para colocar o numero ou valor do `font-size` que
>   queremos com que o texto fique e ao mesmo tempo mover o `input range`
>   para o lugar onde supostamente este valor ficaria situado no `input range` seria melhor ainda.

Comment: É isto que procuras? -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lucp945b/1/

Comment: Tal e qual, era mesmo isto que queria @Sergio! :D Obrigado. posta aí como resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que te falta então é inserires no elemento `#valor-fontSize` o valor do input. Podes fazer isso com jQuery assim:

```
 $('#valor-fontSize').html(tamanhoDaFonte);
```

Eu usei assim no exemplo em baixo:

```
$("#fader").on("input change",function () {
    var size = this.value + 'px';
    $('#v-28').css("font-size", size);
    $('#valor-fontSize').html(size);
});
```

mas também podias fazer

```
$('#valor-fontSize').html($('#v-28').css("font-size"));
```

para ter a certeza que o resultado é certo.

```js
$("#fader").on("input change",function () {
    var size = this.value + 'px';
    $('#v-28').css("font-size", size);
    $('#valor-fontSize').html(size);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="valor-fontSize">--px</p>
<input class="none" type="range" min="14" max="40" value="0" id="fader" step="1" >
    
<p id="v-28">
Após uma viagem que se prolongou por mais de nove anos e em que percorreu 4,8 mil milhões de quilómetros a New Horizons passou o mais perto de Plutão às 11:49 TMG (12:49 em Lisboa) em piloto automático, divulgou a NASA na rede social Twitter.
</p>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lucp945b/4/

**Nota:** O Internet Explorer trata os eventos à sua maneira isso quer dizer que neste caso é melhor usar `input` e `change` para ter o comportamento que precisas.

Comment: Boas @Sergio tudo bem? Eu estou com um dúvida aqui relacionada com este código. Eu experimentei usar este `input range` no Internet Explorer mas parece que ele não está a funcionar e não estou a perceber porquê. Nem o texto, nem o número de pixeis aumenta... http://jsfiddle.net/Lucp945b/1/

Comment: @Chun o IE é especial, eu devia ter testado lá :) Usa os dois eventos `input` e `change` e já vai funcionar. Vou juntar isso na resposta também.

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado =)